# Submit form and do controller action from ViewComponent in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I want to add ListItems from a form in a ViewComponent in an ASP.NET 5, Mvc core application.

The component view (Views\Shared\Components\AddListItem\Default.cshtml):

```
@model ShoppingList.Models.ListItem
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <!-- some fields omitted for brevity -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Description" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The ViewComponent controller (ViewComponents\AddListItem.cs):

```
namespace ShoppingList.ViewComponents
{
    public class AddListItem : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public AddListItem(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string listId)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> Create (ListItem listItem)
        {
            _context.ListItem.Add(listItem);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return View(listItem);
        }

    }
}
```

The Component is invoked in home.cshtml:

```
@{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@Component.Invoke("AddListItem", @ViewBag.DefaultListId)
```

However, I cannot get this to work. Nothing is added.

Comment: How are you calling this ViewComponent?

Comment: @{
            ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    }
    
    @Component.Invoke("AddListItem", @ViewBag.DefaultListId)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rename `AddListItem` to `AddListItemViewComponent`. This is a convention that is used by ASP.NET to find the component - that is ViewComponents need to end with a `ViewComponent` suffix. If you don't want to do it this way, you could decorate the class with the `[ViewComponent]` attribute and set the name property to whatever name you require.

Also, the `Create` method will never be invoked and ViewComponents will never respond to an `HttPost` because it's only purpose is to display view and not to execute code in response to a postback. The View will only either call `Invoke` or its asynchronous version `InvokeAsync` and nothing else.

It's a bit confusing at first but an easy way to think about it is like a powerful `Partial` in the sense that you can do more stuff in the *component* class, DI friendly, and is easier to test as well.

The ASP.NET team has a page that explains ViewComponents [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components#creating-a-view-component)

Comment: I think the link changed or that section is no longer available...    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components

Comment: You mean I can not call HttpPost method in viewcomponent?

Comment: @AProgrammer, that's correct. ViewComponents are designed to render stuff and not to process requests.

Comment: but how do you then handle a ViewComponent where it has functionality which is specific to the ViewComponent.... like a control which has search... where do you put the search action....

Comment: Is there some alternative where I can use HttpPost request on partial component? I need have selectlist - dropdownlist on viewcomponent or partialview.

Comment: This is honestly a fairly big limitation on VC's. RenderAction() allows us to do get/post with forms which gives us options. I keep hearing VC's is RenderAction() replacement but honestly it doesn't look like it. It seems more limiting sadly. This has been a handful of years, has this been "fixed" yet?

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for your help, @Dealdiane.

In case anyone intested, here is the working code:

Views\Shared\Components\AddListItem\Default.cshtml

```
<form asp-controller="ListItems" asp-action="QuickCreate">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="No" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="No" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="No" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
 ...
```

Controllers\ListItemsController.cs

```
    // POST: ListItems/QuickCreate
    // Create item without showing view, return to home 
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> QuickCreate(ListItem listItem)
    {
            _context.ListItem.Add(listItem);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Redirect("/"); 
    }
```

Comment: The link is 404