# How to have OnPostAsync work on a PartialView rendered on my Layout?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a layout (`_Layout.cshtml`) that i want to render a view (`Feedback.cshtml`) onto as a seperate page alongside the `RenderBody()`. The view itself will come off from the right hand side of the layout, using a button to toggle it paning to and from the right. On that view there is a form for feedback. Below is example code for the files mentioned:

`Layout.cshtml`

```
<div class="feedback">
    @await Html.PartialRender("Feedback", new FeedbackModel())
</div>
<div class="content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

`Feedback.cshtml`

```
@model FeedbackModel
<div id="offcanvas formContainer">
  <form id="feedbackForm" method="post">
    <!-- Form fields -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

`Feedback.cshtml.cs`

```
public class FeedbackModel : PageModel
{
    <!-- Properties and fields --!>

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        <!-- Transform data, Add data to DB via repository methods --!>
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Everytime I click the "Submit" button on the Feedback page, it does nothing. It doesn't call the post method at all. If I append a `asp-page-hander="@Model.OnPostAsync()"` on the form or an `onclick="@Model.OnPostAsync()"` on the button - then before the layout even fully loads, it fires the `OnPostAsync()` method immediately, without me even opening the partial view on the page or clicking the button. Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

I thought this logic could instead be moved to a ViewComponent but I am not sure how I would be able to do `OnPostAsync()` when the only supplied method is `InvokeAsync()`.

Comment: So your project is razor page and  you  wanna render an individual razor page in _Layout.cshtml directly, The form can't be submitted to the post method?

Comment: You need to set the form's or submit button's action (probably as `asp-page`) otherwise the post method will use the same url as the current request.

Comment: Looks like you could do with the Bootstrap Offcanvas component for your feedback widget: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/#placement

Comment: Apologies for a bit of confusion.  @Jeremy Lakeman The @page directive is not on the feedback page since partial views can't have @page on them so I can't use `asp-page`. @Xinran Shen you are correct. @Mike Bind I am using an offcanvas, the form is in that offcanvas (updated the above code)

Comment: Then I don't think you can use a page model handler, if this isn't a valid razor page. Either way, you'll need the form to post to the endpoint.

Comment: I am still not sure why don't you use view component here, I think it is more suitable than using razor page

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you @XinranShen. I wouldn't know how to implement it but what I do know is that my custom OnPostAsync method won't work in a view component based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399296/submit-form-and-do-controller-action-from-viewcomponent-in-asp-net-core.
Although if you do find a work around, i'd be glad to see it as an answer!
My comment on the accepted answer elaborates on what my current implentation does.

Comment: The thing about a ViewComponent is that bits of the implementation are spread around the project. You have the UI in a folder nested in the Pages/Shared folder somewhere and an endpoint defined in an MVC controller or as a minimal API request handler perhaps. I like the Razor Pages as a Partial idea because everything is together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's one way. Create a Razor page called Feedback (as you have done) containing the form. Here's the PageModel:

```
public class FeedbackModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public void OnPost() 
    { 
        // process the feedback        
    }
}
```

And here's the view:

```
@page
@model WebApplication3.Pages.FeedbackModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<h3 class="fw-light text-muted">Provide your feedback!</h3>
<form id="feedbackForm" method="post">
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label asp-for="Comments" class="control-label"></label>
        <textarea asp-for="Comments" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success submit" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note that the `Layout` is set to `null`. We only want the form HTML. Also, the submit button is `type="button"` so that the form is NOT submitted when it is clicked. In addition, it is wired up with a `data-bs-dismiss` attribute so that it closes the offcanvas when clicked.

Add the offcanvas HTML to the Layout page:

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasRight">
    <div class="offcanvas-body"></div>
</div>
```

Along with a button to open it:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary feedback" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight">Feedback</button>
```

Finally, add the following script to the Layout page that fetches the HTML for the form when it is clicked and includes it in the offcanvas. It also wires up a click event handler to the non-submit button that posts the content of the form to the `OnPost` handler of the Feedback page:

```
<script>
    const feedbackButton = document.querySelector('button.feedback');
    const offCanvas = document.querySelector('#offcanvasRight .offcanvas-body');
    feedbackButton.addEventListener('click', _=>{
        fetch(`/feedback`).then(response => response.text()).then(html => {
            offCanvas.innerHTML = html;
            const form = offCanvas.querySelector('#feedbackForm');
            const submit = form.querySelector('button.submit');
            submit.addEventListener('click', _=>{
                const formData = new FormData(form);
                fetch(`/feedback`, {
                    method:'post',
                    body:new URLSearchParams(formData)
                });
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I eventually sucumbed to this solution. While it doesn't use the code-behind, it does the job fine. I just had to create a stand-alone Feedback Controller with my method and call it via AJAX when the submit button was clicked.  Thanks for the answer :)